# How to get product views, bounces and transactions data from google analytics api

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to retrieve data about specific products from my site from GA Api. I was trying to use `pagePath` filter to get accurate data but it seems to work only for pageViews.

What filter should I use to track e-commerce data per product/page?

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Answer (score 1):

These are all the valid dimensions for use with eCommerce data. I think you might be able to use productName. For more information you can look at the [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/).

- ga:transactionId
- ga:affiliation
- ga:sessionsToTransaction
- ga:daysToTransaction
- ga:productSku
- **ga:productName**
- ga:productCategory
- ga:currencyCode
- ga:checkoutOptions
- ga:internalPromotionCreative
- ga:internalPromotionId
- ga:internalPromotionName
- ga:internalPromotionPosition
- ga:orderCouponCode
- ga:productBrand
- ga:productCategoryHierarchy
- ga:productCategoryLevelXX
- ga:productCouponCode
- ga:productListName
- ga:productListPosition
- ga:productVariant
- ga:shoppingStage

Answer (score 0):

Bounce rate is a session metric, you can base it on the pageview of the product page not on the product itself.